# Reading images into Ebooklib.Epub in Python 3.4

Tags: python

I want to make an ebook using ebooklib that imports a cover in Python 3.4.

In Python 2 it works fine like this:

```
im = open('image.jpg').read()  
book.set_cover(file_name=image.jpg',content=im,create_page=True)
```

In Python 3.4 it fails with:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte.

Apparently reading an image via the open method no longer works but I cannot find how to do it otherwise in Python3.

I tried using codecs module:

```
im = codecs.open("image.jpg",'r', 'encoding='utf-8')
```

> Result: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

I tried using Pillow:

```
im=Image.open(path+'mn_epub.jpg').load()
```

> Result: TypeError: object of type 'PixelAccess' has no len()

I also tried various other Pillow operation but I could not find anything to make it work.

Comment: which version of **Pillow** did you use? It seems to work on both Python 2 and 3

Comment: It seems that the latest version of Pillow supported for python 3 is 3.0.0 and you are using 3.4

Comment: Pillow 2.7 but Pillow itself works fine, also in Python 3.4, but it just does not work as content in the .set-cover method of ebooklib.epub. I cannot find what would work as content.

Answer (score 2):

The library seems to have some unicode problems.
Here's a shim that monkey patches the library and makes the problem go away; at the start of the script, after importing the library, include this code:

```
from ebooklib import epub
original_get_template = epub.EpubBook.get_template
def new_get_template(*args, **kwargs):
    return original_get_template(*args, **kwargs).encode(encoding='utf8')
epub.EpubBook.get_template = new_get_template
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mean to necro an old post but this is the only post I found relating to a problem I had, so figured I'd throw this here for anybody else who stumbles on this post.

I also had a lot of problems dealing with images and the ebooklib library. I stumbled across [this question regarding the charmap encoder with JPEG files,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099686/python-encodedecode-error-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte). JPEGs are saved as binary and need to be read as such, so instead of calling

`im = open('image.jpg').read()`

You need to call

`im = open('image.jpg', 'rb').read()`

This is probably something that changed between Python 2 and 3.